# Determine the base where the following numbers are in an arithmetic progression

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$34_\alpha, 63_\alpha, 112_\alpha$$

I did:

$$34_\alpha + r_\alpha = 63\alpha \\ 63_\alpha+r_\alpha=112_\alpha \\ 112_\alpha = 34_\alpha+2r_\alpha \Leftrightarrow 112_\alpha -34_\alpha = 2r_\alpha 
$$

Not sure where to go from here. I tried to convert these numbers to decimal but I don't know how many digits r has so that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Oops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since they are in arithmetic progression, $63_{\alpha}-34_{\alpha}=112_{\alpha}-63_{\alpha}$. We can express these in terms of $\alpha$; for example, we have $112_{\alpha}=1\cdot\alpha^2+1\cdot\alpha+2$. Then, our equation becomes $$(6\alpha+3)-(3\alpha+4)=(\alpha^2+\alpha+2)-(6\alpha+3)$$
which simplifies to 
$$\implies \alpha^2-8\alpha=0.$$

$\alpha$ is clearly a positive integer, so $\alpha=8$.